# Function not being recognised due to multiple frames in Tkinter application

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a Tkinter application which has multiple frames. When you click the <kbd>add</kbd> button it takes you to another frame. You then press the <kbd>add assessment</kbd> button which has the command `display`. In this command, it packs a progress bar and button, which has another command `step`, onto the `HomePage`. I have defined `step` above the `display` command, however when I run the program an error occurs saying `step` is not defined. I believe this is due to the multiple frames but I am not sure how to fix it.

```
import calendar
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import *
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
from time import strftime
from datetime import timedelta, datetime, date

class StudyFriendO(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title("StudyFriendO") #naming window title
        self.geometry('850x830') #size of window

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        #### ADDED
        self.shared_data = {  # Variables shared by all pages.
            'name': tk.StringVar(value=''),
            'assessment': tk.StringVar(value=''),
            'due_date': tk.StringVar(value='')
          
        }

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (HomePage, AddPage): #list of multiple frames of program
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(HomePage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

    def step(self): #or frame1
        self.my_progress['value']+= 5
        

    def display(self, cont):
        frame1: HomePage = self.frames[HomePage]
        frame1.my_progress = ttk.Progressbar(frame1, orient='horizontal', length=300, mode='determinate')
        frame1.my_progress.place(x=460, y=460, anchor='center')
        frame1.my_button = tk.Button(frame1, text="Progress", command=self.step)
        frame1.my_button.pack(pady=20)


        
class HomePage(tk.Frame):

    

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        #label = tk.Label(self, text="Home", font = LARGE_FONT)
        #label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        add_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Add", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(AddPage))
        add_button.place(relx=0.8, rely=1, anchor='se')

        

        


class AddPage(tk.Frame):

        
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)


        add_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Add Assesment", command=lambda: controller.display(HomePage))
        add_button.place(relx=0.5, y=560, anchor='center')

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Home", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(HomePage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.pack()

        

app = StudyFriendO()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need `self.step`.  It's a member of the class.

Comment: Thank you, I added this and the progress bar now appears on the `HomePage` frame, however when I press the progress button to increase the progress of the progress bar, I get the error `my_progress['value']+= 5
NameError: name 'my_progress' is not defined`

Comment: You didn't show us that code and we can't read your mind, but it's almost certainly the same problem.  If you create `my_progress` in one function and you expect to use it in another, then it has to be stored in a member, like `self.my_progress`.

Comment: I have edited code in original question. I am now getting error `'_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'my_progress'`

Comment: `my_progress` is created as an attribute of the instance of `HomePage`, so use `self.frames[HomePage].my_progress['value'] += 5` instead.